# How to display line using Measurelt between two vertex

Tags: measurement

[image: No line]
I'm using Blender version 2.83.  I have enabled the Measurelt addon. I can view the distance between two vertex in the Measurelt panel, but I cannot figure out how to display the line and measurement in the 3D viewport.  In the picture I have select two vertex assigned them to group C and changed the color to red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to click the *Show measurements* button.

[image]